# ggplot2 plot an angle between two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot an angle between two lines using ggplot2, meaning something similar to the bold red line in the plot below. Is there an easy solution to this?

[image: plot_with_red_line]

Data and code to make the plot without the red line:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  line = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  x = c(1, 5, 1, 3),
  y = c(1, 3, 1, 5))

ggplot(
  df, aes(x, y, group = line))+
  geom_path()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at `geom_curve`, e.g. :

```
ggplot(  df, aes(x, y, group = line))+
  geom_path() +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 1.5, y = 2, xend = 2, yend = 1.5), curvature = -0.5, color = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]

You will have to tweak it a bit to use it in a more robust, automatic way, for example:

```
red_curve <- df %>%
  group_by(line) %>%
  summarise( avg_x = mean(x),
             avg_y = mean(y))

ggplot(  df, aes(x, y, group = line))+
  geom_path() +
  geom_curve( data = red_curve, aes(x = avg_x[1], y = avg_y[1], xend = avg_x[2], yend = avg_y[2]), curvature = 0.5, color = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `geom_arc` of the `ggforce` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

angle <- function(p, c){
  M <- p - c
  Arg(complex(real = M[1], imaginary = M[2]))
}

O <- c(1,1)
P1 <- c(5,3)
P2 <- c(3,5)
a1 <- angle(P1, O)
a2 <- angle(P2, O)

df <- data.frame(
  line = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  x = c(1, 5, 1, 3),
  y = c(1, 3, 1, 5)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = line)) +
  geom_path() + 
  geom_arc(aes(x0 = 1, y0 = 1, r = 1, start = a1, end = a2), 
           color="red", size = 2, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

The arc does not look like a true arc circle. That's because the aspect ratio is not set to 1. To set the aspect ratio to 1:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = line)) +
  geom_path() + 
  geom_arc(aes(x0 = 1, y0 = 1, r = 1, start = a1, end = a2), 
           color="red", size = 2, inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: wow - that is a nice solution! Would you mind explaining the angle function? Is the output in radians?

Comment: @SteenHarsted Yes the output is in radians. This function gives the angle between the horizontal line passing by `c` and the line passing by `c` and `p`.